# Is there a whereis command equivalent on PASE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, pase

The [whereis](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) command lets me find the location of a command that is on my path on linux, amongst other things. Is there an equivalent on PASE? If so, do I need a PTF?

Comment: What's PASE and PTF? Is there a locate command?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin PASE is basically an AIX subsystem for the IBM i, the spiritual successor to the AS/400. A[ PTF or "program temporary fix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Program_temporary_fix) basically a patch for the OS or other software that IBM provides for the midrange. So, my question is basically, is there a whereis like command for AIX, is it also included with PASE (because not everything in AIX is included), and if its not on my system, what do I have to install to get it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. If it is anything like other Unix OSs, you can make scripts. It would not be hard to write a script that checks each directory in the path for the command you specify. I could write it in bash, but I don't know if that would help you.

Comment: Would the which command work for you? The docs say it is supported.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Thanks!! `which` works, forgot all about that command. Please make it an answer so I can mark it correct. Yes my next step was to write a script. bash is available for PASE, but the default shell is sh, which I believe is generic bourne, so I'd write the script with that because I deal with client machines. Most of my clients have minimal PASE environments.

Comment: ksh should also be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the PASE command list, `which` should be available. It should do almost the same thing as `whereis`.

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```